# Identify when a file was Deleted

Tags: file-system, file-management, files, delete, history

Some files suddenly went missing from my Android Device. Is there a way for me to Identify when a file was Deleted? I don't need to recover them (for now), but I just want to have a clue when it was deleted/removed so i can further investigate.

Comment: No, I don't believe so. Android does not log file deletion.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root acess you can try app like [Undeleter Restores File And Data](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fahrbot.apps.undelete).

You can search for the deleted file and as well as recover it.